# Universal App, Should I need to target separate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have recently started a Universal App project.

Does the Universal app automatically filter out images targeted for iPhone and iPad for the corresponding device? Or does it just copy the full data set including unnecessary images (i.e., images of the wrong size) for iPhone or iPad? How can I avoid that?

Comment: To avoid unnecessary images; you can either create separate apps (that is, not create a universal one), or you could make those images downloadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, universal apps generate just one binary that includes all image resources.

Comment: Yeah, definitely. It's one single, distributable bundle. That's the definition of a universal app: one app, two platforms.